# R: Pulling values from a second dataframe by indexing with values from another dataframe

Tags: r, apply

For every entry in a column of dataframe #1, I want to see if that value is in a dataframe #2 and then grab a value from a particular column from the second dataframe, else 0 if it can't find it. Is there a way to use one of the *apply functions for this?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  key1 = c("A","B","C","E")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  key2 = c("X", "A", "C", "D", "E"),
  val2 = as.integer(c('1','2','23','41','99'))
)

#Answer should be a vector like this:
x <- as.integer(c('2','0','23','99'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will give your the results in your example, but if the `key` appears more than once in `df2` it will return only the first result.  If that is not what you want, please describe the desired output for that scenario.

```
x <- as.integer(df2[["val2"]][match(df1[["key1"]], df2[["key2"]])])
x[is.na(x)] <- as.integer(0)
```

`match` returns the locations of the positions of matches of its first argument in its second.  `match` will return `NA` for non matches, which will create a `NA` value when it indexes into `df2[["val2"]]`, so those values have to be changed to `0` to get the final result.

Comment: Thanks! That will do what I need.

Comment: Glad to help.  If that solves the problem, accepting the answer lets people know that a solution has been found.